# Regex Pattern to Extract Email Data

Tags: c#, regex, multiline, multilinestring

I'm retrieving raw text (includes header, and message) from a POP server. I need to capture everything after the header which is terminated by a blank line between it and the user message.

At the same time I'm wanting to ignore anything from original messages if it's a reply. The start of a reply for the emails I'm parsing start with

```
------Original Message------
```

An example email might look like this

> Return-Path: ...
>   ...
>   More Email Metadata: ...
>
> Hello from regex land, I'm glad to hear from you.
>   ------Original Message------
>   Metadata: ...
>   ...
>
> Hey regex dude, can you help me? Thanks!
>
> Sincerely, Me.

I need to extract "Hello from regex land, I'm glad to hear from you." and any other text/lines prior to the original message.

I'm using this regex right now (C# in multiline mode)and it seems to work except it's capturing ------Original Message------ if the body is blank. I'd rather just have a blank string instead.

```
^\s*$\n(.*)(\n------Original Message------)?
```

**Edit**
I haven't down voted anyone and if you happen to downvote, it's usually helpful to include comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you not use [DotnetOpenMail](http://dotnetopenmail.sourceforge.net/)? Using a regex to do this is a wrong approach, you'd be better off using a dedicated email handler instead....

Comment: I'm using a POP3 client that I was told to use and instead of retrieving messages as objects (as I would prefer), I can only retrieve raw text for each message. Otherwise this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Uhhh... that does not really make sense using regex for this... what pop3 client are you using - that pop3 client should be taking care of the handling of the body of the message etc... otherwise regex would not be needed!!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help tommie. Let's put it in this perspective then. I have PO3 mail client code and I'm extending it to instantiate a MailMessage object for each message retrieved from the POP server. Now I'm writing methods to extract portions of the raw text to hydrate the object properties.

Comment: And I agree.. all of this wouldn't be needed if that were the case :)

Comment: tommie, I think I may be asking for too much in a regex capture. I'm going to try out DotnetOpenMail. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you have an extra `\n` inside the parenthesis. If the body is blank, there is no extra newline there. Therefore, try this:

```
^\s*$\r\n(.*)(^------Original Message------$)?
```

If you don’t want the newline at the end of the body, you can still use `string.Trim()` on the matched part.

**Note:** This assumes that the input uses `\r\n` line terminators (which is required in e-mail headers according to the MIME standard).

Comment: This produces the same results.

Comment: @jlafay: Yeah, sorry. It should be `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace `(\n------Original Message------)` with `(?=(\n------Original Message------))` lookahead to not return that part, just to ensure it's there

Comment: This is better. The problem is that it doesn't account for emails that don't contain "Original Message". Much closer though, thanks.

Comment: What are the alternative terminators other than `original message` ?

Comment: I just want it to stop capturing before original message line. Not all emails will have that line, just most of them do. So if that line doesn't exist it's a new email and not a reply.  I want all of that captured.

Comment: Who gave me a downvote and what's the reason?! Perhaps try `(?=(\n------Original Message------|$))` which should take you to the end of the message.